# Xamarin.iOS and RFComm

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I was exploring codes for bluetooth communication using rfcomm. I was able to implement this in `xamarin.android` native, but for `xamarin.ios` I was not even able to find a sample, just found samples with BLE. So can you please forward me or even better- answer if the rfcomm is possible with xamarin.ios? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iOS devices do not implement the Bluetooth RFCOMM (SPP) profile
>   • Instead Bluetooth accessories can use iAP profile to exchange data with iOS devices
>
> – iAP is RFCOMM based connection (similar to SPP)
>
> – It uses Apple proprietary iAP application protocol
>
> – Allows data exchange between Apps and the accessory

Via: Silicon Labs Wireless and RF Solutions website

If your bluetooth device is `MFi` (Made For iPhone) compatible:

[Apple's MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)

[CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html)

Comment: thanks, so if I would like to exchange data between windows and iOS (we did this with android and windows with no problem), is it possible or not?

Comment: You *could* use the iAP2 protocol and use the raw data channel for transfer, but that is not supported out of the box on Windows (at least as far I know as it is not an official supported profile) so you would have write a lot of code on Windows and it is *slow*...I do no know you data throughput requirements, but not streaming any over that ;-) Bluetooth LE via CoreBluetooth framework is the only real way to go (without using external MFi adapters) with iOS/iPhone/iPads

Comment: Many Thanks! I Will look into that!